# Stream from file with <fstream>

Tags: c++, fstream

How it's possible to read characters from file without loosing the spaces?
I have a file which contains for istance this:
*The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.* 
When I read from file (a character a time), I lose the spaces, but the all other characters are correctly read. Why? 
This is an example of code:

```
unsigned int cap = (unsigned)strlen("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");
char c[cap];
int i = 0;
while (!fIn.eof()) {
    fIn >> c[i];
    ++i;
}

for (int i = 0; i < cap; i++)
    cout << c[i];
```

When i print the array, all spaces are missing. Could you tell me how I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the stream manipulators declared in `<iomanip>`.

`std::noskipws` is the one you want, which instructs stream extraction operators not to skip whitespaces.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream ifs("x.txt");

    ifs >> std::noskipws;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(ifs),
              std::istream_iterator<char>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
```

The other option is to use raw input functions `fstream::get()`, `fstream::read()`.

Comment: I assume this is because the istream::operator>>() was designed to be a console input method? (similar to how arguments to a program are tokenized by spaces). As opposed to other read/getline functions available in istream that act more like a file reader?

Answer (score 2):

Use the method "get":

```
ifstream in("try.in");
char c;
while((c = in.get()) && in) {
  cout << c;
}
```

Comment: In which header get() is defined?

Comment: For this use you need both fstream and iostream.

Comment: how does  `(c = in.get())` actually set c equal to the next character. From what I understand putting that in the while loop just checks to see if there is another character. Can you explain that please?

Comment: This is off topic for the question. Try to read the information available online and if there still is something unclear post a separate question

Comment: istream::get() returns a char and increments to the next char; https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/

istream::peek() also returns a char, but does not increment; maybe you were thinking of that?

Comment: @diox8tony but I mean to increment the char. Why do you think I should not?

Answer (score 1):

By default an istream has the skipws (skip whitespace) flag set. This skips leading whitespace when reading.

You can turn it off using std::noskipws from <iomanip>

```
fIn << std::noskipws;
while (!fIn.eof()) {
    // etc.
}
```